# Ionic: Camera options not working - picture not saved, strange error

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8, ionic-framework

I'm running iOS 8 on my iPhone 6 and want to use the Camera plugin for Ionic.
I did the same thing, following http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/

The camera starts and I can take a picture and click 'Use Photo' but then I get this error:

**Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.**

This is the additional code to take a picture. I allowed access in config.xml.

```
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
            Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
                                     console.log(imageURI);
                                     $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
                                     }, function(err) {
                                     console.err("error"+err);
                                     }, {
                                     quality : 75,
                                     destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                     sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                                     allowEdit : false,
                                     encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                                     targetWidth: 100,
                                     targetHeight: 100,
                                     saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                                     });
            };
```

I tried to update the ios platform (http://ionicframework.com/blog/looking-sharp-on-the-iphone-6/), maybe that's the cause, but then I get this:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasvanommeslaeger/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/update:21:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
Error: /Users/thomasvanommeslaeger/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/update: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Thx!

Comment: I am getting the same error. Has the OP found any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to maintain the image aspect ratio - try removing the height and width options. I was seeing similar errors when trying to parse in params that caused the plugin to die.

Try using the example code as described at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#CameraOptions-quirks